# $\int \limits_0^{\infty} x^2 \exp(-2x^2) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to evaluate this integral?

$$\int \limits_0^{\infty} x^2 \exp(-2x^2) dx$$

I found similar problem, but don't know how to apply them here.

What do I have to substitute?

Comment: Do it by parts.

Comment: I hope you know the integral of $e^{-x^2}$ from $0$ to $\infty$...

Comment: Yes, that should be $\frac{\pi}{2}$..

Comment: @kaos: NO. It should be $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$. Please check it.

Comment: Yep, sorry. Typo..

Comment: @kaos I provided a solution that actually is quite fast and robust with respect to evaluating $\int_0^{\infty}x^{2n}e^{-x^2}dx$ integrals.  Let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I really like it. My only problem is that it might not be valid to use in the test Im learning for. But I will keep it in mind in case a similar problem appears :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting

$$\begin{align}&u=x&u'=1\\{}\\&v'=xe^{-2x^2}&v=-\frac14e^{-2x^2}\end{align}$$

we get your integral is

$$I=\overbrace{\left.-\frac14xe^{-2x^2}\right|_0^\infty}^{=0}+\frac14\int_0^\infty e^{-2x^2}dx$$

Now substitute $\;u=\sqrt2\,x\;\implies\;du=\sqrt2\,dx\;$ , and we get

$$I=\frac1{4\sqrt2}\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}du=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{8\sqrt2}$$

Comment: Ah, that was my mistake. You have to pull $x^2=x\cdot x$ apart. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If we replace $x$ with $\sqrt{\frac{y}{2}}$ we have:

$$ I = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}y^{1/2}e^{-y}\,dy = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{4\sqrt{2}}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{8}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}.$$
We have:
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$
since $\Gamma(x+1)=x\cdot \Gamma(x)$ follows from integration by parts and $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$ since you know in advance the value of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx$, i.e. $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: Referencing the gamma function isn't really evaluating the integral. You've basically just looked up a value in a table instead of employing traditional calculus techniques to actually evaluate it. Moreover the gamma function is likely well beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: it is not my fault if $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\,dx $$ is *the definition* of the $\Gamma$ function, so that evaluating that integral *is equivalent* to computing a value for the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: Yes I agree but you didn't compute the value for the gamma function, instead you just stated it.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: explanation added.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going for. I've seen multiple people do this and it gets under my skin a little. It's great for mature mathematicians like you and I but doesn't do much for students who are struggling with the basic concepts. Thanks for adding an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

We define the function $I(a)$ as

$$\begin{align}
I(a)&\equiv\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Now, taking a derivative with respect to $a$ in $(1)$ reveals that

$$\begin{align}
I'(a)&=-\int_0^{\infty}x^2e^{-ax^2}dx\\\\
&=-\frac14\sqrt{\pi}a^{-3/2} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Setting $a=2$ in $(2)$ and multiplying by $-1$ gives the desired result

> $$\begin{align}
> -I'(2)&=\int_0^{\infty}x^2e^{-2x^2}dx\\\\
> &=\frac18\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
> \end{align}$$

---

**NOTE:**

We can extend the usefulness of this approach by noting that

$$\begin{align}
I^{(n)}(a)&\equiv \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx\\\\
&=(-1)^n\int_0^{\infty}x^{2n}e^{-ax^2}dx\\\\
&=(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}a^{-(2n+1)/2}\\\\
\int_0^{\infty}x^{2n}e^{-ax^2}dx&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}a^{-(2n+1)/2}
\end{align}$$

We can use $(2n-1)!!=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n\,n!}$ to write

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^{\infty}x^{2n}e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{(2n)!}{4^n\,n!}a^{-(2n+1)/2}}$$

Comment: Damn, this is a beautiful way to do it! I guess this is the Feynman way to integrate. Is it very, very clear you can differentiate under the integral symbol, perhaps using Leibniz ? +1

Comment: @Dr.MV my slow typing didn't let me post first the differential process of evaluation. Good job on the evaluation.

Comment: @Leucippus Thanks!  And my slow typing has impacted me too.  ;-)))

Comment: @Timbuc Yes, Feynman's "trick" works nicely here.  And yes, the differentiation interchange is legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

There are often several ways to evaluate some integrals. Here is one of the less standard ways.

Consider the integral
\begin{align}
I(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 \, e^{- a x^2} \, dx
\end{align}
for which 
\begin{align}
I(a) &= - \partial_{a} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a x^2} \, dx 
= - \frac{1}{2} \, \partial_{a} \left( \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \right) 
= \frac{1}{4a} \, \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}. 
\end{align}
Where $a=2$ the result desired is obtained.

Integral evaluation for clarity:
\begin{align}
J(a) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a x^{2}} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{a}} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, t^{-1/2} \, dt \hspace{10mm} t= a x^{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}} \, \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}.  
\end{align}

Further calculations:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{2n} \, e^{-a x^{2}} \, dx &= (-1)^{n} \partial_{a}^{n} \left( \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \right) \\
&= \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n+1} \, n! \, a^{n}} \, \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} 
\end{align}

Comment: It looks like this is the way Dr.MV did it. Thanks for your effort, especially the last general equation helps alot.

Comment: Good solution!! +1